# Visual Studio Code extensions not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio code for a while now on different devices, I have installed the following extensions:

```
vscode-styled-components

Prettier - Code formatter

JavaScript (ES6) code snippets

HTML Snippets

HTML CSS Support

File Utils

ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native snippets

advanced-new-file
```

some of the extensions do not work on my new device like `HTML Snippets`, even if it is enabled.

**I need to know that how to enable all the extensions installed in vscode and Is there any way to manage the new extensions installed**

Comment: Did you checked that extension version is compatible for your VSCode version?

Answer (score 0):

can you enable only HTML Snippets and disable all extensions? If it works, it may have a problem with other extensions.I know different pc its working, but try this.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.